# Run PowerShell script on on-premise servers from azure functions

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

Is there any way , we could run the PowerShell scripts on the on premise servers from the azure functions .
I have created hybrid end point in the function app and 
Connected to sql instance ,but could not work with 
Powershell script .
 It's giving access denied error.

Is it supported in azure functions ?

Comment: did any one face this issue?